# What is the SQL query for user name and the number of common books?

Tags: sql

I have `Users`, `Books`, and `BookUser` tables.

`UserID` and `UserName` are in the `Users` table. `BookID` and `BookName` are in the `Books` table. In the `BookUser` table it combines `BookID` and `UserID`, so this `BookUser` table shows which user has read which book.

I need to write SQL queries to find the following:

- the number of books that a user reads
- the name of other users who read the same books
- the number of common books between users?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i guess you need to ask your teacher for this one. too hard basket

Comment: Table structures with sample data if posted will be helpful

Comment: Absolutely willing to help you do this. But that requires you show some effort first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic way you'd go about structuring the queries for each of those requirements:

```
--The number of books that a user reads
select count(bu.BookID) 
from BookUser bu 
join Users u on bu.UserID = u.UserID
where u.UserName = 'whatever'

--The name of other users who read the same books
select distinct u2.UserName
from Users u
join BookUser bu on u.UserID = bu.UserID
join BookUser bu2 on bu.BookID = bu2.BookID and bu.UserID <> bu2.UserID
join Users u2 on bu2.UserID = u2.UserID
where u.UserName = 'pick one'

--The number of common books between users
select distinct u.UserName, u2.UserName, count(*)
from Users u
join BookUser bu on u.UserID = bu.UserID
join BookUser bu2 on bu.BookID = bu2.BookID and bu.UserID <> bu2.UserID
join Users u2 on bu2.UserID = u2.UserID
group by u.UserName, u2.UserName
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you've used `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` for the number of common books between users?

Comment: Because that will also show users who have no books in common with other users.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't think it should be considered as "in common" with anyone else.

Comment: Well, I can understand that. I appreciate seeing information like that, but the left join can go. I've just removed it.